# A question regarding Worldly Cardinals and L

Tags: set-theory, philosophy, forcing

For some $L_\kappa$ in the constructible hierarchy, does there exist a $\kappa$ such that $\kappa$ is a worldly cardinal and that $L_\kappa$ contains all of the constructible reals?

The motivation for the question is as follows:  in order to understand whether 'adding Cohen reals' is a "legitimate expansion of the mathematical ontology" (this a direct quote from Linnebo's "The Potential Hierarchy of Sets") according to the potentialist conception of the cumulative hierarchy, I email Prof. Linnebo with an example that wrongly assumes that from the potentialist point of view, L is completed. Prof. Linnebo kindly points this out to me and, in a later email, states that "We can complete something iff that something is all contained in some $V_\alpha$." If one wishes to identify a possible world as a model of ZFC (for the purposes of my example--one has to have a ground model in order to have a forcing extension, right?) then having a stage $L_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is a worldly cardinal large enough to have $L_\kappa$ contain all of the constructible reals would seem to produce a model of ZFC+(V=L) to which one can add Cohen reals to form the forcing extension M[G] which violates CH however one wishes.

Comment: So you're looking for a counterexample to Linnebo's potentialist? Could you say a little more why the existence of such an $L_\kappa$ would provide one?

Comment: Actually I am not.  I have been reading Linnebo's papers and find that the potentialist position has some merit.  What I am interested in finding out is whether the operation of 'adding Cohen reals' to a model of ZFC+(V=L) and forming a forcing extension M[G] where CH fails constitutes, for a potentialist, a "legitimate expansion of the mathematical ontology."  In order to do this I have to have, for some $\kappa$ and $L_\kappa$, $L_\kappa$ be a model of ZFC since a potentialist does not accept that L is a completed whole.  This means $\kappa$ for $L_\kappa$ must be worldly in L so that

Comment: $L_\kappa$ satisfies ZFC in L and one has a completed model (for a potentialist) for ZFC+(V=L).

Comment: (Actually V=L should be $V_\kappa$ = $L_\kappa$ for this example). Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'm not sure that the existence of such an $L_\kappa$ really tells us much about whether the potentialist will (or should) think there's a world corresponding to $M[G]$. On one way of developing the potentialist position, at least, there won't in general be such a world. In particular, if they accept what's called "Maximality", i.e. any set that can be formed is formed, and "Priority", i.e. the elements of any set must have existed prior to the set, then every world corresponds to a $V_\alpha$.

Comment: @GME:  The existence of such an $L_\kappa$ is not supposed to tell one whether a potentialist will or should think there is a world corresponding to M[G]--all the existence of $L_\kappa$ does is give the potentialist an actual model of ZFC+($V_\kappa$ = $L_\kappa$) from which to construct the forcing extension M[G] in which CH and thus GCH is false.  The fact that one can, from $L_\kappa$ form a forcing extension in which CH (and GCH) is false via adding Cohen reals begs the question 'is adding Cohen reals an "acceptable expansion of the mathematical ontology"?' for a potentialist.

Comment: As to why I believe it might be, there are, for me, two reasons.  One is the following quote from Linnebo's paper "The Potential Hierarchy of Sets" found on pg. 218:  "Consider a set 'a' and some subset b $\subseteq$ a  that is present at some later world [possibly 'b' is a Cohen real?--my comment].  When 'a' [read a=$\omega$--my comment] was formed, all the elements of 'b' [as a Cohen real--my comment] must have been already available.  When 'a' was formed, we therefore had the ability to form 'b'.  But was this ability exercised?  According to the Principle of Maximality--which says that

Comment: we always form all the sets we are capable of forming--the answer is yes and (ED--$\subseteq$) will thus hold."

Comment: This dovetails into my second reason.  Consider the axiom of powerset, and translate its quantifiers into Linnebo's modalized quantifiers.  The 'necessisarily for all u' modalized quantifier relating to the 'u $\subseteq$ a' sentence in the powerset axiom can be translated as 'for all possible worlds for all u' such that 'u $\subseteq$ a' which (to me, at least) reads 'for all possible subsets 'u' of 'a' ' where the powerset is a completed whole and (ED--$\subseteq$) holds.  In the case where there are so many subsets of 'a' that the powerset does not form a completed whole then

Comment: (ED--$\subseteq$) does not hold and for ordinary set theorists the subsets of 'a' form a proper class. In any case, if possible worlds = models of ZFC then forcing extensions M[G] are accessible from the ground model M (according to Linnebo's definition): M R M[G] $\Rightarrow$ $\mathbf D$(M) $\subseteq$ $\mathbf D$(M[G]), and adding generic sets (some of which are Cohen reals) is an expansion of the mathematical ontology.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm not sure I'm seeing the train of thought here, but perhaps I need to think about it more. Here's a question. For any set $x$ whatsoever, we can ask: is $x$ a legitimate expansion of the mathematical ontology? That is, does $x$ correspond to a possible world by the potentialist's lights? Why is asking that question with $x = M[G]$ particularly interesting?

Comment: @GME:  Well, for one thing, when one deals with forcing extensions M[G] of a ground model M, there is a natural Kripke model formed by having the possible worlds of this particular Kripke model be the models of ZFC, say, and the accessiblilty relation relates a model M to its forcing extensions M[G].  What is interesting about this is that Hamkins and Lowe proved the following theorem about this particular Kripke model:  "If ZFC is consistent, then the ZFC-provably valid principles of forcing are exactly S4.2." Coincidentally, Linnebo's potentialist set theory contains quantified S4.2.

Comment: It is also interesting to note that M[G] is formed by M by adding a new 'ideal element' G (an expansion of the  mathematical ontology).  Since G is an ideal element, it is reasonable to ask whether the addition of a new 'ideal element' is a legitimate move, mathematically.  Hence the question.

Comment: It certainly seems like a coincidence (without further info). Similarly for the use of the term "ideal" in forcing (assuming you're alluding to its other use for something like "potential" (for instance, in Jane's "Idealist and Realist Elements in Cantor’s Approach to Set Theory" (2010))). Anyway, thanks for the discussion!

Comment: @GME:  If you are interested in Hamkins' and Lowe's work on the modal logic of forcing, look on the website www.boolesrings.org for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes for trivial reasons: every real in $L$ appears in $L_{\omega_1}$, so if $\kappa$ is worldly then of course every real in $L$ lives in $L_\kappa$.

If I understand your motivating paragraph correctly, you also want to argue that if $\kappa$ is worldly then it is worldly in $L$ and that in this case $L_\kappa\models \mathrm{ZFC}$. Both of these things are true, but showing them might be a good exercise for you.